# Xamarin Android Output redundancy in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.android, mono

I have this code in visual studio on my Xamarin android Project:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", barcodes));
```

barcodes is a List and I logically want this output:

```
5099924337427
4053804309851
```

and I get this:

```
5099924337427
08-24 13:44:24.883 I/mono-stdout(21154): 5099924337427
4053804309851
08-24 13:44:24.884 I/mono-stdout(21154): 4053804309851
```

Everytime I write output the messages is doubled. Is there a Way to get rid of the mono-stdout line?

Comment: I don't think so, and it's really a pain in the ass, I have ended using a VS plug-in which colorizes the output based on regula expressions, in this way you cand prepend a tag and distinguish the lines you're interested.

Answer (score 1):

EDITED :
Alright after some tests :

- Console.WriteLine print twice the message, one with time header
- Android.Util.Log.Debug print the message with a time header, a custom header and your message

  `ex > 01-01 04:44:10.379 D/[Dashboard][INFO] ( 3291): Hello!`
- Trace.WriteLine print the message with a quite smaller header, a custom header, and your message.

  `ex > [0:] [Dashboard][INFO] : Hello!`

On above examples "[Dashboard][INFO]" is my custom header, "Hello!" is my message. If you do not want any custom header, just use String.Empty.

Test out and pick your favorite !

Comment: this gives me "08-24 14:08:12.440 D/        (22484): 5050749233929" without the repeating which is better